# Why does the cube explode when passive rigid object has this shape?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have some experience in blender. But I still didn't find the answer why this explosion is happening when I make this type of a background.

[Here is the project file](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/4Ik__BuJdM71wQ). Just press play and you will see the difference.

Comment: Please don't share your file on a non-English site where the instructions are in Russian! You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

Change the Plane's <kbd>Shape</kbd> setting under <kbd>Collisions</kbd> from <kbd>Convex Hull</kbd> to <kbd>Mesh</kbd> and your cube animation will work correctly.

[image]

Comment: Hello John, what happened to your rating (199?), or are there 2 John Easons?

Comment: @moonboots: if you look at his profile and his number of answers: there must be a second one ;)

Comment: @Chris Wow that's confusing, it should not be allowed :((

Comment: you made my day :D here is the "original" : https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/104232/john-eason

Comment: Aha! Thanks guys (and especially chris)! My rating suddenly went back to a much earlier version over a week ago and I couldn't find the later user number which you need to get them merged! https://blender.stackexchange.com/contact?topic=4